# Query posts from category based on a filter most favorited

Tags: categories, functions, filters

I have one question. I need to query posts from category based on the filter most favorited ( http://pastie.org/2751114 ) which is placed in custom_sort.php to my index.php page

This is how the posts from categories are called ( http://pastie.org/2751131 ) in index.php.

Is there any way to get the posts from category based on the most favorited filter?

Thank You so very much in advance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`query_posts` accepts custom query variable as arguments. So assuming that adding

```
?sort_by=most_favourites
```

to an url alters the sort order to sort by the most favourites (i.e. you've set `sort_by` as a recognised WordPress query variable, and setting it sorts the returned posts accordingly) then, try:

```
$args = array(
    'cat' => $cat_lists[$i],
    'showposts' => intval(get_theme_option_by('bn_list_per_item', 6 )),
    'sort_by' => 'most_favourites',
    'post_type' => 'post');
```

That should return the set number of posts from the category selected, in order of '`most_favourites`'.

**Update:**

To alter the the value of `sort_by` for category with ID 30 (say), put the following, after `$arg` and before `query_posts`:

```
 if($cat_lists[$i]==30){
    $args['sort_by']='most_commented';
}
```

Comment: HAHAH it did the trick, but it's not most_favourites, instead is: most_favorites . One letter to much. Thank You so very much. You are an inspiration and a big help. I really appreciate it!

Comment: is it possible to give the option for one of 3 categories to show different sort? I would like to create a most_commented filter on 1 category. Is it possible?

Comment: That's because I was writing in English :P. Glad to help :D. As for using a different sorting method, you can just use an if statement to change the $args array when $cat_lists[$i] == some ID. You just need to alter the sort_by line to: 'sort_by'=> 'most_commented'

Comment: I'm a bit of a noob so could You tell me if the IF statement comes after the query or inside the $args? could you give me an example for category number 30 in pastie maybe so I can understand and use the code?

Comment: Updated my answer to include the IF statement

Comment: thank you so much it works like a charm. You are my life savior :D